# Edit Neovim terminal commandline within the same Neovim instance

Tags: terminal, external-command, neovim

In bash one can edit the current commandline in `$EDITOR` by pressing `<c-x><c-e>`.

I am running bash inside a terminal buffer within Neovim. I would like to be able to press `<c-x><c-e>` and have Neovim open a new buffer (`:new`), in the same Neovim instance, with the current contents of the commandline. When I close that buffer (`:bdelete`) I would like to have the contents of the buffer replace what was on the commandline.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does typing `q:` in normal mode do what you want?   (See `:help cmdline-window`)

Comment: @EvergreenTree ah, I should have made the distinction between the vim commandline and the commandline of the shell running in the terminal buffer more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now turned the script below into a plugin: [nvim-editcommand](https://github.com/brettanomyces/nvim-editcommand), or if you don't mind starting you terminals with a plugin command [nvim-terminus](https://github.com/brettanomyces/nvim-terminus) provides a few more features

---

Finally got it working in pure (ugly) vimscript:

```
    " set the name of the current buffer, useful for setting the name of terminal buffers
function! SetFileName()
  execute 'file ' . input('Enter name: ')
endfunction

" - yank from last line with prompt ('> ') to last line into register c
" - clear commandline
" - call function
tnoremap <c-x> <c-\><c-n>:execute ':?> ?,$y c'<cr>A<c-c><c-\><c-n>:call EditCommandline()<cr>

function! EditCommandline()
  " clear search highlighting
  let @/ = ""

  " - set an autocmd on the current (terminal) buffer that will run when the buffer is next entered
  " - put from register c (where the new command will be)
  " - remove the autocmd
  " - go to insert mode
  autocmd BufEnter <buffer> put c | autocmd! BufEnter <buffer> | call feedkeys('A')

  " get all text after prompt '> '
  let s:command = strpart(@c, strridx(@c, "> ") + 2)

  " open new empty buffer
  new 

  " make buffer a scratch buffer
  setlocal buftype=nofile
  setlocal bufhidden=hide
  setlocal noswapfile

  " put command into buffer
  put! =s:command

  " remove extra lines
  %join!

  " copy buffer to register when it is closed
  autocmd BufLeave <buffer> :%yank c

endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you asked, but it might be closer to what you really want:

In bash, you can type in vi mode! Just put type `set -o vi` into bash and you'll be able to hit escape to switch to normal mode. Stick it in your .bashrc file for it to become an incredibly useful permanent change.

edit: I just realized that this might be why you can't (by default) exit Neovim terminal mode with escape.